# Build Your Apps With Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I saw apple's news as below.

**Build Your Apps With Xcode 5.1.1**

> Starting May 15, 2014, new apps and app updates submitted to the App
>   Store must be built with Xcode 5.1.1. This release is available
>   through Software Update on the Mac App Store.

`Question is:` How do they find out my build taken from Xcode 5.1 or 5.1.1? Or any specific reason for this? Is Xcode 5.1.1 have default project setting ? Apple force to change dev to this setting? or any other? Because Before I do update, I want to know that reason?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple's decision to change the required Xcode build version, and we are not Apple, nor privy to their internal decision making process.

Comment: Simply put: you need to do it because Apple said so. We can only speculate as to why it's necessary, or how they'll detect this. Maybe there's a magic number in the binary somewhere, or in the upload request.

Comment: I know, we must do. If they tell , you must do this means, there should be an point behind that. I want to know that. People either may or maynot know that reason. Actually many of us, didn't know that. If any one knew means, this question and answer will useful for all of us. You and me didn't know that reason which doesn't mean  to there is no reason. Am I right?

Comment: @Mani whoooooah man... that's like... deeeeep

Comment: @Mani *policy* dictates like this are tended to make it easier for support. The less versions of a piece of software that are supported the easier it is to fix problems. As to the how - lots of ways (embedded metadata in the binary, certain forms of optimization).

Answer (score 3):

They can tell because Xcode puts the version info into the `Info.plist`s that are created when you archive a product and when you create an IPA (I presume this also happens with any builds submitted with Xcode to iTunes Connect):

```
<key>DTXcode</key>
<string>0510</string>
<key>DTXcodeBuild</key>
<string>5B130a</string>
```

Comment: +1 for you. Why do they force us to change to 5.1.1..?

Comment: Because they control the whole system - see all the comments on your question! :D

Comment: All are said like that only. When I change from 5.0 to 5.1? They didn't told like this, but now why do they force us?