# The bundle is invalid. New apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with public

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, app-store

Since yesterday I can not validate the app but in last week it works great and now it didn't. I get the error:

> The bundle is invalid. New apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with public.

I'm using xcode 5.1 and SDK 7.1

Have someone any idea?

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Made a quick fix on the code, didn't touch anything related to profiles. Also I'm using Xcode 5.1 and SDK 7.0.

Comment: Here is what they said [xcode 5.1 and SDK 7.1](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=04252014a)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Problem is not compliance with apple's role. According to [apple's news](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=04252014a),

> Starting May 15, 2014, new apps and app updates submitted to the App
>   Store must be built with Xcode 5.1.1

Take build with Xcode 5.1.1 and check it. Xcode version info taken into binary during archive process, [see this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23364988/build-your-apps-with-xcode-5-1-1)

Comment: This seems like a good call. Yesterday the problem started and yesterday was May 15th. Coincidence? I don't think so!

Comment: I've got the same error after building with the latest non-beta Xcode 5.1.1. It turned out that you can't use developer preview versions of Mac OS for builds you want to submit to App Store. In my case, I was using the latest developer preview of Mac OS 10.10 (I guess the App Loader checks the "BuildMachineOSBuild" param in the Info.plist inside your built .app bundle). Building on 10.9 solved the problem.

Answer (score 6):

i also had the same problem with Xcode 5.1.1

you have to update your Application loader for resolve this problem because today onwards Apple accept APP Binary only from applications loader,

for latest version of application loader.

go to [iTune Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com) login with your Apple credential

Go to --> Manage Your Apps

from the bottom links goto [Download Application Loader](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_2.9.1.dmg) . its 82 MB .dmg

open your project with XCODE 5.1.1

now set your app deployment target to 7.1 or 7.0 (minimum)

now try to upload your binary with latest Application Loader

Thanks

Comment: Here is a link on [Resources page in iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/resources_page), where you always can find latest version of the Application Loader